# Making room for wire nuts for a fixture screwed onto a conduit

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I am replacing a line-voltage outdoor lamp. The old lamp was screwed directly onto a length of 1/2" metal conduit coming up from the ground. Whoever put this together originally just twisted the wires together and taped them, and shoved the results down into the conduit. There is no space inside either the new or old fixture to put wire nuts. I seem to think that I've seen fixtures atop conduit along paths before, but of course my visual memory is not perfect. The alternative that occurs to me is to add a box (or perhaps just a conduit body) atop the conduit to make a place to put proper wire nuts.

Alternatively, one might be able to persuade wire nuts for #14 wire to fit into the conduit by putting them down there one-at-a-time. What's a good practice that conforms to code here?

You can see the new fixture https://www.build.com/kichler-15205/s869822?uid=2221476&null.

The old fixture is not materially different.

Comment: It would help significantly if you would [edit] to include pics of the old installation and the new lamp. Obviously, twisting & taping wires is _not_ a suitable method for attaching them. Since whoever did this work originally was willing to short cut on that, it's likely they were willing to shortcut by not installing a box, either. I'd make a stab that the new lamp (and old) require mounting via a JB, and that you'll have to source one, firmly attach it to the conduit, then you'll be fine.

Comment: Product page says: "This item needed to complete installation" and links to a post mount with adequate internal space to make junctions. https://www.build.com/kichler-15276/s84974?uid=841989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the information at the linked page:

> **Compatible Accessories:**
>
> For stem mounting, purchase the 15645, 15656, 15657, or 15658 stems *and the 15276 power post*
> <sup>Emphasis added</sup>

The [15276 power post](https://www.build.com/kichler-15276/s84974?uid=841989) says (among other things):

> **Features:**
>
> - 2 1/4" inside diameter accepts conduit of different sizes
> - Made of impact and corrosion resistant PVC, suitable for wet locations
> - *Eliminates the need for above-ground power source or junction boxes*
>   <sup>Emphasis added</sup>

This power post, at 2.25" diameter, will provide the room for the wiring necessary to make the light work.

To go along with your $200 yard light, you need a $34 "junction box" to mount it.

Comment: Similar short-pole-junction-box devices are available for about half that price elsewhere. Along with lights that are a lot less than half that price. But not my house/yard.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact ha! Yeah, I bought the $5 solar lights that broke after being hit by the mower a couple of times. Haven't replaced 'em. But, if this is what the OP wants (and there's nothing wrong with that), then he needs to get _all_ the proper pieces. Pointing out availability of other, less expensive options is helpful!

Comment: I'm generally of the opinion: Let people buy what they want, but help them make educated decisions. Back around April 2020, many "nonessential" stores were closed. In my area lots of exceptions, fortunately (I'm in IT, IT was considered essential, as were stores selling IT equipment). Some places were taking it to an extreme - saying a grocery store could open but not a TV store (same here, essentially) but *also* that a grocery store couldn't sell a TV (or furniture or clothing, etc.) Which I found absurd. I took a picture when waiting in line at Costco of someone buying milk, cereal and

Comment: a big screen TV. Which I thought was great! I am not into big screen TVs, but for someone who found that would be a way to deal with being mostly stuck at home for a few months, it seemed like a great idea. I'll spend my money on what I want to spend it on and you can spend it on what you want to spend it on. I'll get the $50 light and spend the leftover $150 on something else that others might think is a waste. My choice.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is that the fixture I am replacing was installed screwed straight to the top of the conduit. Sometimes, things in this house were actually done according to code. The old fixture looks a lot like the new one. Yes, I chose to buy the expensive one due to issues of color and availability.

Comment: You are free, @bmargulies, to spend your money on whatever you choose - no judgement from me. Some people spend $5 on a cup of coffee, but I'm not into that. I spend money on tools and computers - I'm sure there are some who think I'm insane! Glad this worked out for you.

Answer (score -1):

lamps that connect to conduit usually include an internal junction box.
use that.

Comment: According to the OP, "There is no space inside either the new or old fixture to put wire nuts."

Comment: possibly these are not intended to be attached to conduit.

Comment: I would go with "probably" or even "most likely".

Comment: It has a 1/2 inch thread at the bottom. Period.

Comment: Yes. So do many floodlights. They are not intended to mount to conduit, they are intended to mount to a threaded exterior box or box cover.